# Give a kit when entering a region? - Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I would like to give players a kit when they enter an area if they are a certain rank.

For Example:

rank1 gets kit1
rank2 gets kit2
etc.

Is this possible? If so, what plugin would I need?

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you mean by rank and region? Are you using other plugins to define those?

Comment: I am using PEX for permissions, which I cannot change, but I am  using essentials for kits but i can change that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there aren't any plugins to do so, I'd recommend you to play with WorldGuard-based permissions on the /kit commands.

Cf. Regions flag: allowed-cmds

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WorldGuardExtraFlags plugin to expand the flags you are able to set in WorldGuard regions.

Aside of the normal `command-on-entry` flag you can then also set `console-command-on-entry` to execute commands as console when a player enters that region, instead of only commands the player has access to.

I use that to do a few things when people enter the PvP arena, such as disabling all their cosmetics, giving them some temporary effects and setting a PvP rank. It can also set keep inventory and keep exp within a region, prevent elytra flight and prevent items losing durability.